# disable onclick event on div when clicking on inside <a> link (No js framework)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this piece of code:

```
<div id="mydiv" onclick="ajax_call()">
    <a href="http://myurl">Mylink</a>
</div>
```

I'd like ajax_call() to be called only when clicking on empty space inside div but not on "Mylink". Is it possible without any external javascript framework?

Moreover I have this piece of css:

```
div#mydiv:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Is it possible to disable the :hover stylesheet when the cursor is placed over "Mylink" (in order to suggest that clicking on "Mylink" won't trigger ajax_call() but will take to myurl)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, what you need is the event `target` || `scrElement`

Like

```
  function ajax_call() {

    var target = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;

    if(target.id==="mydiv") { alert("good to go"); }

  }
```

[See : http://jsbin.com/qujuxufo/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/jobokuyo/1/edit)

---

***Edit/Update ( missed the second part )** - Started to answer this before the q was closed - but might as well as it now ..*

For the second part of the question - it is not possible to set parent elements in CSS ( it flows top to bottom ) - for that some more JS is needed.

[See http://jsbin.com/cileqipi/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/jodihavi/1/edit)
CSS

```
#mydiv:hover { background-color:green; color:#fff}
#mydiv.anchorhover, #mydiv.anchorhover:hover { background-color:white;}
```

Then JS

```
  var _mydiv =  document.getElementById("mydiv");
  var _mydiv_anchors = _mydiv.getElementsByTagName("a");

  function toggleClass() {
    var addClass=true, cls="anchorhover";
    if((_mydiv.className).indexOf(cls) >= 0){ addClass=false; }
    if(addClass) {
      _mydiv.className=_mydiv.className+=' '+cls;
    } else {
      /* remove */
      _mydiv.className=_mydiv.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'),' ').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }
  }

  for(var i=0, len=_mydiv_anchors.length; i<len; ++i) {
    _mydiv_anchors[i].onmouseover = toggleClass; 
    _mydiv_anchors[i].onmouseout = toggleClass; 
  }
```

^ That feels like quite a trip compared to how simple jquery abstracts it .. >

```
$("#mydiv a").hover(function() {
   $(this).parent().addClass("anchorhover");
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("anchorhover");
});
```

---

Either way, the principle is : to add a style class to the parent element on mouseover and remove it on mouseout

Comment: * the shorthand regex for the remove Class I found on SO donkeys back and can't credit as I lost the name ! Sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot! Extremely detailed.

Answer (score 2):

Attach the function at child element with `click` event, After clicked on child element it's handler stops the immediate propagation,  As a result `ajax_call()` will not be invoked.

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv" onclick="ajax_call()">
    <a href="http://myurl" onclick="notCall(event)">Mylink</a>
</div>
```

**javaScript**

```
function ajax_call(){
    alert("empt space");
}

//this function stops the propagation and not triggered above
//function when clicked on child element.
function notCall(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/79QwW/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want but if I keep my imagination may be that this work, lucky !

```
$("div#mydiv a").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background-color","transparent")
})
```